# Google maps API v3 controls missing in Bootstrap 3.0

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

[sample link here](http://demo1.dealerpeak.net/?fuseaction=content.geoTest)

I'm trying to get the map controls to show on a Bootstrap 3.0 site on a map I'm writing using Google's v3 map API but they seem to be missing no matter what I do. I've read several posts that talk about using the following styles:

```
<style>
#as-loc-map{
    width:90%;
    height:700px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;   
}
#as-loc-map label {
  width: auto;
  display:inline;
}
#as-loc-map img{
    max-width: none;
}   
</style>
```

OR
    
     .google-map-canvas,
     .google-map-canvas * { .box-sizing(content-box); }

This has not helped. I cannot seem to get the controls to appear. When I make the same map on a non-boostrap page I can find a div with a class of gmnoprint that contains some of the controls in the inspector. On the bootstrap page that div does not appear.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Obviously it's forced by this file: http://cdn.vehiclemall.com/MediaLibrary/JavaScript/final/CoreWebsite.js (remove it and the controls appear). As long as this file is compressed you better ask the provider of this file for a fix.

Comment: It turned out to be a prototype.js conflict. I've gotten so used to seeing console errors from that file that I've learned to just ignore them (another department manages that portion of the app).

Thank you!

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the prototype conflict?